# In R, can character strings be imputed from corresponding codes and vice versa?

Tags: r, string, package, imputation

I have a dataset that has code-string pairs.  In other words, there is a column of codes and a corresponding column of character strings that are descriptions of the codes.

The problem is three-fold...

- PROBLEM 1: sometimes codes are missing, but the character string is present.
- PROBLEM 2: Sometimes codes are present, but the character string is missing
- PROBLEM 3: Sometimes the character strings for the same code are distinct strings, but mean the same thing    ("synonyms").

Made-up examples:

```
 +-------+------------------+
 |  CODE |  STRING          |
 +-------+------------------+
 |   A1  |  broken bones    |
 |   A1  |  broken bones    |
 |   NA  |  broken bones    |
 |   A1  |  bones, broken   |
 |   A1  |  bones, fracture |
 |   A1  |  NA              |
 |   B1  |  red blood cells |
 |   B1  |  red blood cells |
 |   B1  |  blood cells, red|
 |   B1  |  NA              |
 |   B1  |  erythrocytes    |
 |   NA  |  broken bones    |
 |   C1  |  liver disease   |
 |   C1  |  liver disease   |
 |   C1  |  hepatic illness |
 |   C1  |  NA              |
 |   C1  |  disease, liver  |
 |   NA  |  liver disease   |
 +-------+------------------+
```

My questions are ...

1. If the code is present, can the character string be imputed?  Vice-Versa as well.
2. Can they be imputed if the strings of the code-string pairs vary, but are repeated? (e.g. hepatic illness)
3. If so, is there an R package that can do this kind of imputation?

Comment: What is the EXACT output you want to see? What is the code you've attempted to get that output?

Comment: I think this will be straightforward if you specify some rules, e.g. are you happy with the imputation of STRING being based on the first time CODE and STRING are both present?

Comment: Hey, thanks for responding.  OK, I want the appropriate codes filled in the CODE column where it has the value of NA.  I want a legitimate string (or synonym) where the STRING is NA.  IOW, the three NA's in CODE would be A1, A1, C1.  The appropriate STRING would be "broken bones" or "bones, fracture", "red blood cells" or the other 2 synonyms, "liver disease" or the other two synonyms.

Comment: As for the code I've developed, it's a matter of approach.... Do I come up with my own code that fills in the values OR is there existing code (R package) that does this already?  Where do I put my time?

Comment: As for the rules, they are kind of loose, so there are options.  The first time the pair was present would be fine, the last would be fine etc.  That is not as significant as the code and the string being corresponding to each other.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way to do it:

```r
get_commonest <- function(level, code, string)
{
  names(rev(sort(table(na.omit(string[code == level])))))[1]
}

codes <- na.omit(unique(df$CODE))
strings <- na.omit(unique(df$STRING))

default_strings <- as.data.frame(sapply(codes, get_commonest, df$CODE, df$STRING))
default_codes <- as.data.frame(sapply(strings, get_commonest, df$STRING, df$CODE))

df$CODE[is.na(df$CODE)] <- as.character(default_codes[df$STRING[is.na(df$CODE)],])
df$STRING[is.na(df$STRING)] <- as.character(default_strings[df$CODE[is.na(df$STRING)],])
```

Giving you this result:

```
df
#>    CODE           STRING
#> 2    A1     broken bones
#> 3    A1     broken bones
#> 4    A1     broken bones
#> 5    A1    bones, broken
#> 6    A1  bones, fracture
#> 7    A1     broken bones
#> 8    B1  red blood cells
#> 9    B1  red blood cells
#> 10   B1 blood cells, red
#> 11   B1  red blood cells
#> 12   B1     erythrocytes
#> 13   A1     broken bones
#> 14   C1    liver disease
#> 15   C1    liver disease
#> 16   C1  hepatic illness
#> 17   C1    liver disease
#> 18   C1   disease, liver
#> 19   C1    liver disease
```

---

The data given in the question is in reproducible format here:

```
df <- structure(list(CODE = c("A1", "A1", NA, "A1", "A1", "A1", "B1", 
"B1", "B1", "B1", "B1", NA, "C1", "C1", "C1", "C1", "C1", NA), 
    STRING = c("broken bones", "broken bones", "broken bones", 
    "bones, broken", "bones, fracture", NA, "red blood cells", 
    "red blood cells", "blood cells, red", NA, "erythrocytes", 
    "broken bones", "liver disease", "liver disease", "hepatic illness", 
    NA, "disease, liver", "liver disease")), row.names = 2:19, class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Thanks Allan!  So you think imputation packages are not the way to go I assume?

Comment: @JoseMorales if you need to use imputation for lots of different things, it's worth investing the time to research which package best suits your needs and learn how to use it. If it's for a single task like the one you describe, it's probably quicker to write your own code. As you can see, my answer works, and took about 10 minutes to write. It would take me longer to find and learn a new package.

Comment: I get you.  Truth is that this example is one case of missing data that I have from 1 table.  I have three tables and if I am to make the biggest one tidy, I'm going to create ALOT of missing data from spreading 1 column. For that, I need to use an imputation package for sure. That has its challenges too as I am not sure how much data has to be present to be able to impute effectively.  My reasoning was since I have to pick a package anyway (e.g. mice), perhaps imputation would be used the the code string as well.  Figured I'd ask tho.  Thanks for your input!!!